# Has someone designed a neural network which can select its own activation functions and/or have multiple activation functions in one model?

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, rnn, convolutional-neural-network, hyperparameter-tuning

I'm wonder if there are any papers or implementations where a neural network has multiple activation functions in a single model (and layer), and preferably also where such activation functions themselves are learned or tuned.

Comment: See here: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1412.6830.pdf